# Does new set pointer to NULL if it throws std::bad_alloc?

Tags: c++, null, new-operator, allocation, bad-alloc

I know doing a `new(std::no_throw)` will set pointer to `NULL` if it failed.
I also know that a normal `new` will throw a `std::bad_alloc` exception if it failed.

Will the normal `new` also set the pointer to `NULL` if it throws? Or should I set it to `NULL` in the `catch()` block?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C++ a bad `new` will throw an exception (unless you use std::nothrow) and the pointer will not be assigned so it'll be whatever it was before the `new` call was made.

However, you may be interested in [this article](http://www.cprogramming.com/tips/showTip.php?tip=64&count=30&page=0) which talks about forcing `new` to return null on failure as you mentioned in your question.

Answer (score 0):

When an exception is thrown, the stack is unwound (running destructors of local objects) until a `catch` stops the exception. There's nothing that automatically sets the pointer to `NULL`, and it's unilkely that one of the destructors does so - it would be a contrived example that did.

Usually, there's no need to set the pointer to `NULL`. In fact, often you can't. Take the following code:

```
try { 
  std::string s("hello, world");
} catch (std::bad_alloc) {
 // ???
}
```

It's possible that the allocation of those 12 bytes fails. The exception will return from the constructor of `std::string`. At that point, the object `s` no longer exists, nor does the pointer `s._SomeInternalName` inside `s`. The compiler will therefor report an error if you try to use `s` in the catch block. And if the pointer doesn't exist anymore, you obviously can't set it to 0.